# How to bind an attribute in ember, which is a combination of a static value and a dynamic value?

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-view

You can bind the class "active" to an element like this

```
<button {{bind-attr class="isActive:active"}}>Test</button>
```

Even static classes are possible:

```
<button {{bind-attr class=":btn isActive:active"}}>Test</button>
```

But how to get a button like this

```
<button {{bind-attr class=":btn :facet%id%"}}>Test</button>
```

to have the value of "id" bound to the static-value?

```
<button class="btn facet384"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try with a helper

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper("btn-facet", function(a,hash){
    return new Handlebars.SafeString('class="btn facet'+a+'"');
});
```

you would have to use unbound on the template I'm not sure how to create an helper that returns unbound values, this is a jsbin of it working, not the nicest way http://jsbin.com/UqERudud/1/edit